# What is the reason for inconsistency of Chrome Task Manager Info Vs Windows Task Manager Info of Chrome Processes?

Tags: windows, multithreading, google-chrome, process

I notice that the mem usage of the processes which google chrome task manager shows are not consistent with the mem usage of the chrome process(es) in windows task manager. For eg in following image Chrome Task manager shows that the largest mem eating process (chrome refers to it as page) is "Plug-in:Showkwave Flash" with 70,600K. In Windows Task Manager largest mem eating chrome process is shown to have 79,364K. There is another one as well in the range of 77K. Why and how does this inconsistency arises. Is it something to do with the some sort of overhead required by windows task manager to calculate the mem usage of each process? Or is it something related to chrome itself.

Another Question: There is always an additional "Chrome" process listed in Windows task manager. i.e in below image Chrome Task Manager lists 15 "pages" whereas Windows Task manager lists 16 chrome "processes" (I'm excluding chrome_frame_helper.exe here. I'm guessing its not a native chrome process.) Whats the reason behind this.

[image]

Comment: I'm just guessing but I would think that the difference is between what data chrome stores and what data windows needs to store about chrome. Ex: permissions, when the task was started, where the executable lives etc.

Comment: Spencer, the kernel has its own data structures and won't leave them in a process' address space ...

Comment: How do you know task manager is just showing the space taken up in a process' address space? That isn't very useful if you're trying to figure out how all your memory is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome probably queries its own processes for more accurate information of the internal data structures instead of just using the externally visible memory the process uses (which includes overhead for the runtime as well).

As to why there is an additional process: The jobs are the rendering processes for the tabs and plugin containers. The additional one is the window frame around the tabs.